# Tag your Doctrine entities easily with FPNTagBundle

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to use https://github.com/FabienPennequin/FPNTagBundle bundle in a sf2.1 project. All done as documentation (with annotations) but i get this error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\TagManager::loadTagging() must be an
>   instance of DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\Taggable, instance of
>   Acme\TagBundle\Entity\Document given, called in
>   /project/src/Acme/TagBundle/Controller/DocumentController.php on line
>   111 and defined in
>   /project/vendor/fpn/doctrine-extensions-taggable/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Taggable/TagManager.php
>   line 201

Plus, when I send php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme I get this:

> Generating entities for namespace "Acme"
>
> [ErrorException]
>
> Runtime Notice: Declaration of Acme\TagBundle\Entity\Tagging::setTag()
>   should be compatible with
>   DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\Entity\Tagging::setTag(DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\Entity\Tag
>   $tag) in /projects/bazar/project/src/Acme/TagBundle/Entity/Tagging.php
>   line 22

May you help me?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

As for the second issue, please remove the functions of your tagging and tag entities(Acme\TagBundle\Entity\Tagging...).
Don't generate entities for your tag bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Implement Taggable interface in you Document entity

```
Class Document implement Taggable{
...
}
```

Comment: Yes. Good hint! This resolve main problem. But how to resolve second error? When I generate entities (all, not only a single entity) symfony generate incorrect getTag and setTag.